# R data.table memory efficient rbindlist

Tags: r, list, memory, data.table

I'd like to rbind multiple datatables in a memory efficient way.

More precisely, I'd like to rbind them one by one, and free memory on the go, so that I can join **n** data.tables of size **k** when my memory is only of size **(n+1)*k**.

I wrote this function hoping to do that :

```
rbindlistOneByOne <- function(l, use.names=FALSE, fill=FALSE, idcol=NULL, verbose = F) {
  ll <- length(l)
  # Handle empty lists
  if(ll <= 0) stop("rbindlistOneByOne : empty list")
  if(ll <= 1) return(l[[1]])
  # Handle normal lists (ll > 2)
  current <- l[[1]]
  res <- current
  l[1] <- NULL
  rm(current); gc()
  for(i in 2:ll) {
    current <- l[[1]]
    res <- rbindlist(list(res, current), use.names = use.names, fill = fill, idcol = idcol)
    l[1] <- NULL
    rm(current); gc()
  }
  return(res)
}
```

Now the problem is that this function **is not** memory efficient, even though I thought it would be.

Do you know why ? Is that because rm does not free memory, and that the data.table called "current" remains in memory ?

Comment: What happens if you use `data.table`'s built-in `rbindlist()` function?

Comment: l <- rbindlist(l) should be very memory efficient since no deep copy is made.

Comment: I've had this exact same problem `gc()` didn't remove from memory like I wanted either.  The (very inefficient way) I solved this was to do a series of operations, write to an RDS file, delete the object and then clear the memory, read the RDS file back in, and continue operations.  I was maxing out the local memory and R would crash so I had to take this approach.

Comment: `gc()` does not free memory. Memory allocation is deterministic in R but memory release is stochastic. There is no way to do what you want to do in R. The best way is `rbindlist` which is the most memory efficient

Comment: @Uwe : it uses more memory than I can afford, and eventually crashes saying "can't allocate X". What's even more surprising to me is that the dataset is 20Go large while I have 64Go of memory. It shouldn't be **that** inefficient isn't it ?

Comment: You probably have already tried to reduce memory footprint of the single data tables? I.e., use of `integer` type instead of `numeric` for "integerish" values (`1L` versus `1` does make a difference), `factor` i.s.o. `character`, `IDate` i.s.o. `Date`, etc.?

Comment: Have you tried `tables()` to show the memory consumption of data.table objects?

Comment: How are the data.tables created or loaded? Is there a chance to bind the tables earlier in the process chain?

Comment: @Uwe : 
(1) Yes I did.
(2) I did not know about this function, I'm gonna read about it asap.
(3) They are created in a foreach loop, and therefore it would be hard to rewrite differently.
Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do what you want to do. Memory release is stochastic in R you can't control it. The use of `gc()` may or may not release memory and it is not under user's control.

From http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html :

> Despite what you might have read elsewhere, there’s never any need to call gc() yourself. R will automatically run garbage collection whenever it needs more space; if you want to see when that is, call gcinfo(TRUE). The only reason you might want to call gc() is to ask R to return memory to the operating system. However, even that might not have any effect: older versions of Windows had no way for a program to return memory to the OS.

In addition calling `gc` is extremely slow. Here a bechmark of your function with and without calling `gc` for a list of 1000 tables of 10 lines

- without `gc` : 8 ms
- with `gc` : 7 s

`rbindlist` is the most efficient way to bind `data.table`

Comment: Thank you. I'll be looking for solutions to rbind in ROM instead of in-memory.